# what correct port no and where to set for sql server mangment studio?

Tags: database-administration, informatica

i have installed sql server managment studio on windows 10. now i am trying to connect sql server from informatica cloud which is asking for host name and port no. host name i found with ipconfig in command prompt. but i see port no is blank in sql server configure mangment, so i set it to default 1433.
but still connection is showing failed. i ran query in sql server DB "

select distinct local_net_address, local_tcp_port from sys.dm_exec_connections where local_net_address is not null;" but getting no result.

is there any additional parameters are required to connect to DB like TLS version or any related entry to connect to TCP.

i am trying to find correct port no for sql server

expected result:- to connect informatica cloud to sql server DB.

Comment: The port is most likely the default 1433. Make sure you get the host right and that the host is accessible from the internet / secure agent location.